# Android Emulator doesn't run in Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, xamarin.android, android-sdk-2.3

I don't know what the warnings mean, but I did everything to reduce the error.
1. Added reference to System.ObjectModel
2. installed JDK 1.8 and added the path to it.
But still I'm facing this error and I don't know what it means. I've put the screenshot on what errors pop up when the deployment on Android Emulator fails.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is quite clear: it can not find your installation of the JDK and android SDK.

So you need to check the settings in Visual Studio:
Tools => Options => Xamarin => Android Settings

There you need to enter the path of your JDK and SDK

You should also check of you downloaded the correct android sdk for your emulator.
In your case that should be API level 19

Comment: Thank you, mate. But the path for JDK and SDK both are there, so I don't understand the error message. I believe the SDK is also the correct one.

Comment: Did you check your environment settings of your system?
maybe there is an other path set for the JDK so VS cannot find it